# php array unique and pushing data

Tags: php, arrays

i got data return from mongodb and as i searched i saw that i cannot user cursor twice so i put all data in arrays and now i need to split the data to unique name, the data i got :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 208
            [data] => 150
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 208
            [data] => 130
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 204
            [data] => 20
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 204
            [data] => 30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => 208
            [data] =>300
        )
)
```

what i need to accomplish is to get unique names and push Data return for each name like that:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 208
            [data] => [150,130,300]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 204
            [data] => [20,30]
        )
)
```

i can get the unique Name's but not pushing the data value to each name

i tried with two foreach loops without success , thanks for any help

```
foreach ($cursor as $document) { 
    $name[] = $document['name']; 
    $data[] = $document['data']; 
} 
$uniName = array_unique($name); 
foreach($uniName as $theName) { 
    foreach($result as $two) { 
        $arr1['name'] = $two['name']; 
        if($theName == $towo['name']) { 
            $arr1['data'][] = $tow['data']; 
        } 
        array_push($result1,$arr1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show us your best attempt please

Comment: what i did is geting the unique names first with array_unique then foreach loop on the unique arrays then one more foreach loop inside the other foreach loop and tried to store only the data to existing array name but with no success, i played with it alot before asking here so i dont have an example to show here because i changed it alot :(

Comment: So you have code, show us it

Comment: someting like that : foreach ($cursor as $document) {

 $name[] = $document['name'];
    $data[] = $document['data'];
}

$uniName =  array_unique($name); 

foreach($uniName as $theName)
{
 
 foreach($result as $two)
 {
  $arr1['name'] = $two['name'];
  
  if($theName == $towo['name'])
  {
    $arr1['data'][] = $tow['data'];
  }
  array_push($result1,$arr1);
 }
 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple foreach loop can be used to create a new array. If you use the `'name'` as the key then this makes it easy to remove the duplicates. All you have to do is check if you saw this `name` before and if not create a new entry in the new array and if you saw this `name` before just add a data item to the data array.

```
$dataArray = 
[
    ['name'=> 208, 'data' =>150],
    ['name'=> 208, 'data' =>130],
    ['name'=> 204, 'data' =>20],
    ['name'=> 204, 'data' =>30],
    ['name'=> 208, 'data' =>300]
];


foreach ($dataArray as $key=>$sub){
    if ( isset($new[$sub['name']]) ) {
        // we saw this one before
        $new[$sub['name']]['data'][] = $sub['data'];
    } else {
        // first time we saw this one
        $new[$sub['name']] = ['name' => $sub['name'], 'data' => [$sub['data']]];
    }
}
$new = array_values($new);
print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 208
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 150
                    [1] => 130
                    [2] => 300
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 204
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20
                    [1] => 30
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot !! RiggsFolly that is perfect :)

Comment: how can i get the result as in my example result ? thanks

Comment: Except for the array keys being 208 and not 0 etc that is the array you asked for. Do you just want the array keys set back to 0,1,2....

Comment: yes please as in my example with array 0,1,2 thank for the help , im trying also at my side :)

Comment: Done, just use `array_values()` to build a new new array with numerics starting at 0

Comment: thanks RiggsFolly , now its perfect and also i learned something more from your code :)